# How to deal with async function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `body` object with different types of elements: (`strings`, `number`, `objects`...).
I need to show the `body` in a table.
In order to do it, I need to print in one table the elements that aren't objects, and in another table the elements that are objects.

So I am calling the function to create an array with object elements (arrObj) and another array with the non object elements (arrSimple).

The problem is that when I go through the `arrSimple` array to print the elements in a table, this array is empty.

Could anyone guide me on how can I resolve this async problem?

```
const DetailResult = props => {

    ...
    const arrSimple = []
    const arrObj = []

    function organizeArray() {
        for (const prop in body) {
            if (typeof (body[prop]) != 'object') {
                arrSimple[prop] = (body[prop])
            } else if (typeof (body[prop]) == 'object') {
                arrObj[prop] = (body[prop])
            }
        }
    }

    function renderGeneralData() {
        organizeArray()

        arrSimple.map((key, i) => {
            <tr key={i}>
                <td width="25%">{key}</td>
                <td>{(arrSimple[key])}</td>
            </tr>
        })

    }

    return (

        <div>    
            <table className='table table-striped'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>General Data</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {renderGeneralData()}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DetailResult;
```

The body object comes from the app component.

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {                       
            dataTable: {                
                transactionID: '',                             
                maxRows: 10,
                currentPage: 0,
                list: {
                    headerList: [],
                    body: []
                }
            }
        }
        this.search = this.search.bind(this)
     }

      search() {
        axios.get(URL)
            .then(resp => this.setState({
                dataTable: Object.assign(this.state.dataTable, {
                    list: [
                        {headerList: ['App name', 'Date', 'Bio data', 'Is verified', 'Actions']},
                        {body: resp.data},
                    ],
                }),

            }))
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

I have a component that contains a search field to make a request

```
 const SearchComponent = props => {    

        const renderDetailResult = 
            <DetailResult list={props.dtObject.list}
                search={props.search}
            /> 

         return (
            <div role='form' className='searchID'>
                <ContentHeader title={props.componentHeaderTitle} />
                <Grid cols='12 9 10'>
                    <input id="cpf" className='w-25 form-control'
                        placeholder='Type the ID'
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid cols='12 3 2'>
                    <IconButton style='primary' icon='search'
                        onClick={props.search}>
                    </IconButton>
                </Grid>
                <Grid cols='12'>
                    {renderDetailResult}
                </Grid>

            </div>
        )
    }

    export default SearchComponent
```

Comment: Where is comming the `body` ? Please show the code where you get it

Comment: @Vencovsky I updated the question

Comment: And where do you call `search` ? `The body object comes from the app component.` where are you passing it? Looking at the two component codes you add, I can't see any relation between then.

Comment: Render `<DetailResult />` conditionally, when body array is not empty.

Comment: @Vencovsky I added the code that link the components. Sorry, I thought it was irrelevent to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing appears is that you are calling a function that returns nothing, so there isn't anything to render.

You need to return the `.map` and return the elements you want.

```
function renderGeneralData() {
    organizeArray()

    // added return
    return arrSimple.map((key, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
            <td width="25%">{key}</td>
            <td>{(arrSimple[key])}</td>
        </tr>
    ))

}
```

**Observation**

You are rendering `<tr>` inside `<tr>`. I recommend removing the

```
return arrSimple.map((key, i) => (
    //returning tr
    <tr key={i}>
        <td width="25%">{key}</td>
        <td>{(arrSimple[key])}</td>
    </tr>
))

<tr>
    // returned tr inside another tr
    {renderGeneralData()}
</tr>
```

I'm not sure how you want to display your data, but I recommend removing one of the `tr` tag.

**Quick tip**

If you want to  remove the `tr` that is inside `.map` you should use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
return arrSimple.map((key, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
        <td width="25%">{key}</td>
        <td>{(arrSimple[key])}</td>
    </React.Fragment>
))
```

## Edit:

I also noticed something weird in your code in this part

```
arrSimple.map((key, i) => (
    <tr key={i}>
        <td width="25%">{key}</td>
        <td>{(arrSimple[key])}</td>
    </tr>
))
```

In this part of the code, `key` will be an element of `arrSimple`. If you do `arrSimple[key]` it will probably return `undefined`. Here is an example

```js
arr = ['hey', 'this', 'is', 'bad', '!']
console.log(arr.map((key, i) => arr[key]))
```

Comment: tku so much for the answer and for the explanation.

Comment: @mr.abdo take a look at the edit, maybe it will help you in other things too